# How to insert image as BLOB into Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, go, blob

I have a database with A_LOB_TABLE table:

[image]

I want to INSERT image as BLOB with any (let's say '1') ID to A_LOB_TABLE using goracle package.

Here is my code:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
defer cancel()

// To have a valid LOB locator, we have to keep the Stmt around.
qry := `DECLARE tmp BLOB;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(tmp, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION);
  :1 := tmp;
END;`
    tx, err := testDb.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer tx.Rollback()

stmt, err := tx.PrepareContext(ctx, qry)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %w", qry, err)
}
defer stmt.Close()
var tmp goracle.Lob
if _, err := stmt.ExecContext(ctx, goracle.LobAsReader(), sql.Out{Dest: &tmp}); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to create temporary lob: %+v", err)
}
fmt.Printf("tmp: %#v", tmp)

// Get file as bytes (it needs to be in the same dir as code is)
dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./sample.png")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(".....Error Opening File")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

if _, err := tx.ExecContext(ctx,
    "BEGIN dbms_lob.append(:1, :2); END;",
    tmp, goracle.Lob{Reader: bytes.NewReader(dat[:])},
); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to write buffer(%v) to lob(%v): %+v", dat, tmp, err)
}

// INSERTING LOB - starting....
_, err = testDb.Exec("insert into A_LOB_TABLE(id, image) VALUES(:1, :2)",  1, tmp)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(".....Error Inserting data - BLOB")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
// INSERTING LOB - ended.
```

It doesn't work though. It outputs error at line

```
_, err = testDb.Exec("insert into A_LOB_TABLE(id, image) VALUES(:1, :2)",  1, tmp)
```

saying:

> dpiStmt_execute(mode=32 arrLen=-1): ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dozens of hours trying to figure out how to accomplish BLOB insertion into OracleDB using goracle Go driver, I got answer.

TL;DR

Full code (obviously adapt variables like DB connection and file location && file name to your needs):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "time"
goracle "gopkg.in/goracle.v2"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("... Setting up Database Connection")
    testDb, err := sql.Open("goracle",
        "sys" +
            "/" +
            "Oracle18" +
            "@" +
            "localhost:32118" +
            "/" +
            "XE as sysdba")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("... DB Setup Failed")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer testDb.Close()

// Get file as bytes
dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./sample.png")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(".....Error Opening File")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

// BLOB creation && passing file into it
directLob := goracle.Lob{ Reader: bytes.NewReader(dat[:])}

fmt.Println("\nINSERTING BLOB - starting....")
// Working BLOB insertion - INSERT COMMAND
_, err = testDb.Exec("insert into AA_LIVE_FRAMES(id, frame) VALUES(:1, :2)",  1, directLob)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(".....Error Inserting BLOB")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println("\nINSERTING BLOB - ended.")

fmt.Println("\nSuccess")
}
```

This is working main.go file.

**LONGER VERSION ANSWER**

*Why this took me so long if code is so simple?*

When I've started to work with that problem, I didn't find any tutorial or examples in the goracle documentation showing how to INSERT BLOB into OracleDB. Sure, there was this goracle.Lob structure with nice function - Read(). It was my first try, declare this goracle.Lob and use it's Read() function, but it gave me errors - nil address and so on. I didn't know why, tried to debug it - without results. Then I went deeper, I pull out some test codes from goracle package showing how to create temporary LOB - some of this code is shown in my question answer. Again, without success. Then, I was trying raw SQL, failed again (I think because my OracleDB is docker - creating directory, which is needed to insert BLOB into OracleDB didn't work; nvm).

And finally, I am not sure why, I have tried struct literal:

```
directLob := goracle.Lob{ Reader: bytes.NewReader(dat[:])}
```

and worked.

Alright, why I am typing all of this? Because, AFAIK, doing this:

```
directLob := goracle.Lob{ Reader: bytes.NewReader(dat[:])}
```

and this:

```
directLob := goracle.Lob{}
directLob.Read(dat[:])
```

should be the same? Or am I completely wrong?